# Upload attachement Orbeon Fatal error: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, file, tomcat, upload, orbeon

When i upload attachment give this error:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ |An Error has Occurred
|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| |Fatal error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| |Application Call Stack
|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| |oxf:/ops/xforms/xforms-server.xpl
|reading processor output      |  37|
|······················································································································|
|element=<p:output name="data" id="xforms-request"/>
| |name   =data
| |id     =xforms-request
|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| |file:/opt/portal/tomcat/temp/upload_1a87ef6c_152e534ba6b__7fff_00000965.tmp
|                              |   1|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| |Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException
|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| |org.orbeon.oxf.xml.XMLParsing$ErrorHandler         |fatalError
|XMLParsing.java               | 215|
|orbeon.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper      |fatalError
|                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter         |reportError
|                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter         |reportError
|                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter         |reportError
|                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner               |reportFatalError
|                              |    |
|xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher|dispatch
|                              |    |
|n.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl|scanDocument
|                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration    |parse
|                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration    |parse
|                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser             |parse
|                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser     |parse
|                              |    |
|processor.generator.URLGenerator$URLResourceHandler|readXML
|URLGenerator.java             |1012|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator$1  |readImpl
|URLGenerator.java             | 538|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read
|ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
|eteRuntimeOutputFilter$ForwarderRuntimeOutputOutput|read
|ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 218|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX
|ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
|n.oxf.processor.validation.MSVValidationProcessor$3|readImpl
|MSVValidationProcessor.java   | 221|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read
|ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read
|ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
|mpl.ProcessorOutputImpl$ConcreteRuntimeOutputFilter|read
|ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 241|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read
|ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX
|ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsDOM4J
|ProcessorImpl.java            | 279|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsDOM4J
|ProcessorImpl.java            | 294|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer       |doIt
|XFormsServer.java             | 123|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer       |access$000
|XFormsServer.java             |  64|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer$1     |readImpl
|XFormsServer.java             |  91|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read
|ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
|eteRuntimeOutputFilter$ForwarderRuntimeOutputOutput|read
|ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 218|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX
|ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
|n.oxf.processor.validation.MSVValidationProcessor$3|readImpl
|MSVValidationProcessor.java   | 221|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read
|ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read
|ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
|mpl.ProcessorOutputImpl$ConcreteRuntimeOutputFilter|read
|ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 241|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read
|ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX
|ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.processor.converter.TextConverterBase|readInput
|TextConverterBase.java        | 113|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.processor.converter.TextConverterBase|access$000
|TextConverterBase.java        |  39|
|.orbeon.oxf.processor.converter.TextConverterBase$1|readImpl
|TextConverterBase.java        |  91|
|---8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<---| |nServlet$$anonfun$service$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply
|OrbeonServlet.scala           |  72| |org.orbeon.oxf.util.ScalaUtils$
|withRootException             |ScalaUtils.scala              |  83|
|orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply$mcV$sp
|OrbeonServlet.scala           |  72|
|orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply
|OrbeonServlet.scala           |  72|
|orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply
|OrbeonServlet.scala           |  72|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.DynamicVariable                |withValue
|DynamicVariable.scala         |  42|
|org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet               |service
|OrbeonServlet.scala           |  71| |javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
|service                       |HttpServlet.java              | 727|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter
|ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 303|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter
|ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 208|
|org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter        |doFilter
|WsFilter.java                 |  52|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter
|ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 241|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter
|ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 208|
|org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.FormRunnerAuthFilter        |doFilter
|FormRunnerAuthFilter.scala    |  26|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter
|ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 241|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter
|ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 208|
|.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$2|apply$mcV$sp
|LimiterFilter.scala           |  92|
|.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$2|apply
|LimiterFilter.scala           |  92|
|.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$2|apply
|LimiterFilter.scala           |  92|
|org.orbeon.oxf.logging.LifecycleLogger$            |withEvent
|LifecycleLogger.scala         | 124|
|rbeon.oxf.servlet.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1|apply
|LimiterFilter.scala           |  91|
|rbeon.oxf.servlet.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1|apply
|LimiterFilter.scala           |  72| |scala.Option
|foreach                       |Option.scala                  | 257|
|org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.LimiterFilter               |doFilter
|LimiterFilter.scala           |  72|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter
|ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 241|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter
|ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 208|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve      |invoke
|StandardWrapperValve.java     | 220|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve      |invoke
|StandardContextValve.java     | 122|
|org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase|invoke
|AuthenticatorBase.java        | 501|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve         |invoke
|StandardHostValve.java        | 170|
|org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve        |invoke
|ErrorReportValve.java         |  98|
|org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve          |invoke
|AccessLogValve.java           | 950|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve       |invoke
|StandardEngineValve.java      | 116|
|org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter        |service
|CoyoteAdapter.java            | 408|
|org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor   |process
|AbstractHttp11Processor.java  |1040|
|e.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler|process
|AbstractProtocol.java         | 607|
|.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor|run
|JIoEndpoint.java              | 313|
|java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor            |runWorker
|ThreadPoolExecutor.java       |1145|
|java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker     |run
|ThreadPoolExecutor.java       | 615| |java.lang.Thread
|run                           |Thread.java                   | 744|
+-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is the file you're uploading particularly large? Are you getting the same error if you're attaching a "tiny" file? Did you change the `properties-local.xml` to persist data somewhere else, e.g. in a relational database?

Comment: I use the database exist db, I tried on a different of formats and file sizes.

Comment: Is this on a UNIX machine? If it is, make sure that the user running Tomcat has the appropriate permissions to write in the Orbeon Forms `WEB-INF/exist-data` directory, since this is where the eXist database is. You'll let me know if this helps.